# SQL multiple COUNT

Tags: sql, count

Let's consider this table:

```
[name] [type]
"Ken Anderson" 1
"John Smith" 2
"Bill Anderson" 1
"George Anderson" 1
"Taylor Smith" 1
"Andrew Anderson" 2
"Dominic Smith" 2
```

and that query:

```
SELECT mates.type, COUNT(*) AS SmithsCount
FROM mates
WHERE mates.name LIKE "* Smith"
GROUP BY mates.type
```

The result should be like

```
[type] [SmithsCount]
1 1
2 2
```

What if I want to get **also** Andersons Count in each group? Like

```
[type] [SmithsCount] [AndersonsCount]
1 1 3
2 2 1
```

And, of course, I want this to be most simple as it can be ;) I'm pretty new in SQL, I readed tutorials on W3 Schools and http://www.sql-tutorial.net/ but there are just poorly exampled basics, any "more" complicated queries. Anybody has some useful links? Thanks.

Comment: What you have is a bad design not a SQL problem. NEVER store first and last name in one field and then try to query on last name. YOu cannot use the indexes when you have a wildcard as the first character. Learn correctly not to ever do this before you learn workaround queries.

Comment: Yep, I know that. That was just an example, not the real problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select type,
       sum(case when name like '% Smith' then 1 else 0 end) as SmithCount,
       sum(case when name like '% Anderson' then 1 else 0 end) as AndersonCount
    from mates
    group by type
```

Comment: I'm using MS Access (not my idea...) however this pointet me to "iif" statement which works the same way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need a pivot table. This is a feature supported by some RDBMS (Oracle, SQLServer and probably others).

A pivot table let's you use values as columns for aggregations. See my post here: [How to transform vertical data into horizontal data with SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071811/how-to-transform-vertical-data-into-horizontal-data-with-sql/4071845#4071845)

The pivot table will alow you to also get the counts of all the other people in your list.

Comment: Well, to the noob who downvoted me: What he needs is a pivot table and he should be introduced to the concept.

Comment: Joe's solution is pretty clear for me but that pivot table could be useful for other things. I'll read about it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is close, but you must use % instead of * as the wildcard character.

```
select type,
    sum(case when name like '%Smith' then 1 else 0 end) as SmithCount,
    sum(case when name like '%Anderson' then 1 else 0 end) as AndersonCount
group by type
```

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL parlance this is not supported in the presentation that you propose.

Standard SQL way would be to first normalize data into mates.first_name, mates.last_name and then do:

```
SELECT mates.type, mates.last_name, COUNT(*) AS last_name_count
FROM mates
WHERE mates.last_name IN ('Smith', 'Anderson')
GROUP BY mates.type, mates.last_name
```

Which would provide output such as

```
type last_name last_name_count
1    Anderson  3
1    Smith     1
2    Anderson  1
2    Smith     2
```

this is the same info that you are looking for, but the format/presentation is not the same.
Historically you were supposed to pivot/crosstab this data in the client application (as part of the presentation layer).

Of course a lot of times it is useful or necessary to do it in SQL layer so extensions to the standard were made, such as [pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) (MSSQL) or [crosstab](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) (postgres), etc...