# Multiple row in self join

Tags: sql

i have table in this format

```
Id  QId   ResourceId ModuleId SubProjId  Comments 
1   1   1   1   2   ffdg    1   1
2   2   1   1   2   dfgfdg  1   1
3   3   1   1   2   hgjhg   1   1
4   1   2   1   2   tryty   1   0
5   5   1   1   2   sdf 1   1
6   5   2   1   2   ghgfh   1   0
7   7   2   1   2   tytry   1   0
8   3   2   1   2   rytr    1   0
```

and i wan result in this way

```
qid  ResourceId Comments   ResourceId  Comments

1   1   ffdg    2   tryty
3   1   hgjhg   2   rytr
```

i tried

```
select distinct  A.qid,A.ResourceId,A.Comments,B.ResourceId,b.Comments
from dbo.#temp A inner join #temp B on A.QId=B.QId and A.[ModuleId]=B.[ModuleId] and a.[SubProjId]=b.[SubProjId]
```

but did not find any luck please help

Comment: I hope this thread helps you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071811/how-to-transform-vertical-data-into-horizontal-data-with-sql

Comment: Explain on which basis result comes out.

Comment: @Nakul :-basically  A.qid,A.ResourceId and [ModuleId] are the common

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert vertical data to horizontal. So you need to create a pivot table. You can find more details here
[How to transform vertical data into horizontal data with SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071811/how-to-transform-vertical-data-into-horizontal-data-with-sql)

Comment: Then why ResourceId and Comments columns exists twice in the result?

Comment: Rashmi Kant..From the result that you have posted, it appears to me that you want to convert vertical data to horizontal and you can do it using Pivot table. Please go thur the pivot table reference link and see if can help you.

Comment: from my query result is coming but its also giving some extra row which i , do not want