# How to list all pairs of location with same area from the table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been trying to find the answer to this question.

List all pairs of locations that have same area. The result should list `(location name 1, location name 2, location area)` where `location name 1` and `location name 2` have same `location area`. This pair should appear only once in the output.

So the table can look like this:

```
(Loc_id, Loc_name, Loc_area)
(1, ABC, 60)
(2, ZXY, 50)
(3, DEF, 60)
(4, YUM, 60)
(5, ZUM, 50)
```

Pairs: `(ABC,DEF,60)`, `(ZXY,ZUM,50)`, `(ABC,YUM,60)`, `(DEF,ZUM,60)`, and so on.

**UPDATE:**

I get a table with first name, second name and location area with Pratik's solution. But, it doesn't give any value in this table.

what if I do this?

```
select t_1.Loc_name name1, t_2.loc_name name2, t_1.loc_area
from Location t_1, Location t_2
where t_1.loc_area = t_2.loc_area and t_1.loc_name<>t_2.loc_name
Order by t_1.Loc_name
```

I get the list of all probable combinations (similar to Rebika's solution below). But now how do i remove duplicates from this list?

I don't want

```
name1      name2     loc_area
ABC         DEF        60
DEF         ABC        60
```

I want

```
name1      name2     loc_area
ABC        DEF         60
ABC        YUM         60
DEF        YUM         60
.
.
.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Wrong start, self join would be better

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071811/how-to-transform-vertical-data-into-horizontal-data-with-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT a.loc_name, b.loc_name, a.loc_area
  FROM LOCATION a, LOCATION b
 WHERE a.loc_area = b.loc_area
   AND a.loc_name != b.loc_name
   AND a.loc_id < b.loc_id;
```

- First condition ensures that records with same `loc_area` are joined.
- Second condition ensures `loc_name` is not joined with itself.
- Third condition ensures only one combination of `loc_name` is returned.

Comment: this is a perfect solution! Guess I needed to add t_1.loc_id < t_2.loc_id;

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify your oracle version, you can use this if you are using Oracle 11g:

```
select loc_area, listagg (loc_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP 
(ORDER BY loc_name) Locations
FROM LOCATION
GROUP BY LOC_AREA;
```

If you are on Oracle 9, try using xmlagg:

```
select loc_area, rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, loc_name || ',')).extract ('//text()'), ',') Locations
from LOCATION
group by LOC_AREA ;
```

source: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_converting_rows_columns.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think following query will solve your question -

```
select t_1.Loc_name name1, t_2.loc_name name2, t_1.loc_area
from Location t_1, Location t_2
where t_1.loc_area = t_2.loc_area
and t_1.loc_area<t_2.loc_area
Order by t_1.Loc_name
```

Comment: this doesn't return any value

Comment: what if I add t_1.loc_name<>t_2.loc_name?

Answer (score 0):

Try  this out -:

**SELECT a.Loc_name locname1, b.Loc_name locname2, a.Loc_area 

FROM Location a 

JOIN Location b 

ON 1=1 

WHERE a.area =b.area and a.Loc_name <>b.Loc_name**

I have avoided those location names that pairs up with the self such as (ABC,ABC). If you want this too remove condition **a.loc_name <>b.loc_name**  in where clause.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This is similar to the one that I updated above. But it still has (abc, def) and (def, abc) pairs which are similar. It should only return either (abc, def) pair or (def, abc) pair.

Comment: Add a.Loc_id < b.Loc_id or b.Loc_id >a.Loc_id in the where clause in above query and you will get the desired result.Noel 's solution is also correct.