# Converting query using not exists

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

I came up with the following query using not in and in. I need to convert it to the one that uses not exists.

```
SELECT T_DATE, T_DEPTIME
FROM TOUR
WHERE T_ID NOT IN (
SELECT T_ID 
FROM RESERVATION 
WHERE R_ID IN (
SELECT R_ID 
FROM PRES
WHERE P_ID IN (
SELECT P_ID
FROM PARTICIPANT
WHERE P_STATE = 'FL')));
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT d.t_date, d.t_deptime
  FROM tour d
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
            FROM reservation a, pres b, participant c
           WHERE c.p_state = 'FL'
             AND b.p_id = c.p_id
             AND a.r_id = b.r_id
             AND a.t_id = d.t_id);
```

Comment: Can you help me with this too.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640043/how-to-list-all-pairs-of-location-with-same-area-from-the-table-in-oracle