# MySQL query to get nearest location from WordPress database WHERE longitude and latitude saved as post meta

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-maps

I have a custom post type "Store" and store address saved in postmeta table as geo_latitude, geo_longitude, geo_public, geo_address as WordPress [recommend](https://codex.wordpress.org/Geodata). Then we have all registered user latitude and longitude and stored in user meta. Now I want to get nearest 5 or 10 store id (basically postid) from the database using [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to calculate the radius.

I found a good thread in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112926/how-to-find-nearest-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-from-sql-database) but there latitude and latitude as table row but my case latitude and latitude is row value (meta value). A sample database structure has attached.

[image: database stracture]

Comment: So the problem is you have the long. and lat. in seperate rows but need them both in the same row?  Basically you're looking for a query to transform vertical to horizontal data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071811/how-to-transform-vertical-data-into-horizontal-data-with-sql

Comment: Yes, something like that. I am following WP recommendation for geo data, and I want to know is it possible anyhow before changing database structure?

Comment: With the link I added to the comment above you should be able to do a query to get it all in one row.

Comment: Yeah, trying to use Pivot table, thanks for the link :)

Comment: Do you think anyhow is it possible to transform vertical to horizontal data and, then use in another SQL query? I mean first I wanna transform to horizontal and the used in the query calculate radius?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it (no pivot table) with self joins:

```
SELECT a.post_id, a.meta_value as lat, b.meta_value as lng, c.meta_value as  address
FROM lbt_postmeta as a, 
lbt_postmeta as b,
lbt_postmeta as c

WHERE a.meta_key = "geo_latitude"
AND b.meta_key= "geo_longitude"
AND c.meta_key= "geo_address"
AND a.post_id = b.post_id
AND a.post_id = c.post_id
```

gives you a table with post_id, lat, lng, address

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for :)